# I want to create a column loop in Python

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl

I want to create a loop in Excel using openpyxl, everything works perfectly, updates my column, but when saving I only value the last value of the last column.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
x = 1
while True:
 wb = Workbook()
 ws = wb.active
 ws['A' + str(x)] = 42
 wb.save("test.xlsx")
 y = input("dasdsa :")
 if y == "ESC":
   break
 else:
   x += 1
   continue'
```

Comment: Is this a typo: "..when saving I only value the last value of the last column." ? Can you clarify ?

Comment: When i brake the loop, and i open de file test.xlsx i see "42" in the column equal to x. Example: I start the loop with x = 1,  and run the loop 5 times now x = 5 and when i open the test.xlsx "42" is on  A5.

Comment: I solved:        from openpyxl import Workbook
x = 1
wb = Workbook()
while True:
    ws = wb.active
    ws['A' + str(x)] = 42
    y = input("dasdsa :")
    if y == "ESC":
        wb.save("test.xlsx")
        break
    else:
        x += 1
        continue

Comment: Please edit your question - not everybody reads the comments.

Answer (score 0):

move `wb.save` into your `if y` block

```
from openpyxl import Workbook 
x = 1 
wb = Workbook() 
while True: 
  ws = wb.active 
  ws['A' + str(x)] = 42 
  y = input("dasdsa :") 
  if y == "ESC": 
    wb.save("test.xlsx") 
    break 
  else: 
    x += 1 
    continue
```